# ASUS Windows 8 Computer Hard Drive

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

My computer starts up normally. Then when it goes to the ASUS load up screen, there is no spinning wheel.

So I go to boot menu and there is some information. There is no clicking in the hard drive.

When I hold esc it loads up two choices, and of course I pick the hard drive. Then it goes to a black screen, it says

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected a lot device and press key.

Could someone please tell me if my hard drive disk is out of place or if my computer is out of wack?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you able to access Windows at all? What were you doing just before it stopped working? Do you have the exact make and model of your computer? Please [edit] your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I had seen similar errors several times, and in almost every occasion, this means the hard drive is damaged, from a cold power-down, a drop from the desk or something similar.

This doesn't mean all data is lost on that hard drive. Sometimes you can use Linux or other tools to read out the data from the tracks that are undamaged. But it's unlikely that the hard drive can be used as a boot disk again.